# connect() to unix:/app_path/shared/sockets/unicorn.[app].sock failed. No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sockets, unix, nginx, unicorn

I deployed a Rails app using capistrano gem on Ubuntu 14.04. Using Nginx, unicorn.

I've followed all the steps in the deployment from http://requiremind.com/deploying-a-rails-app-on-your-own-server-the-ultimate-guide/ but something seems to not be working. I get the message

> "We're sorry, but something went wrong."

Verified nginx is up

```
sudo netstat -plutn | grep :80
```

Output

```
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:80 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 27525/nginx
```

And here is the /var/log/nginx/error.log

> *7 connect() to unix:/home/user/apps/my_app/shared/sockets/unicorn.2dotO.sock failed
>   (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client:
>   client_ip_address, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "http://unix:/home/user/apps/my_app/shared/sockets/unicorn.2dotO.sock:/",
>   host: "server_ip_address"

But the file unicorn.2dotO.sock exists in that location. And not sure why this isn't working!

Unicorn.rb file

```
app_dir    = "/home/user/apps/my_app"
shared_dir = "#{app_dir}/shared"
root       = "#{app_dir}/current"
working_directory root
pid "#{root}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "#{root}/log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "#{root}/log/unicorn.log"

listen "#{shared_dir}/sockets/unicorn.2dot0.sock"
worker_processes 2
timeout 30

# Force the bundler gemfile environment variable to
# reference the capistrano "current" symlink
before_exec do |_|
  ENV["BUNDLE_GEMFILE"] = File.join(root, 'Gemfile')
end
```

Could you please help?

Comment: Is it `2dot0` or `2dotO`?  I see both in your question.  Is that a letter O or a number zero?

Comment: That was the issue! Thanks for catching that